# Can you refer to a var using a string in PHP?

Tags: php, variables

What I mean is can I do something like this...

```
$number = 1;
$varname = 'number';
```

Now I want to get the value of $number by using $varname so something like...

```
echo $($varname);
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: [`${$varname}`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), usually an array is a way better solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use {} instead of ():

```
echo ${$varname};
```

Or even shorter:

```
echo $$varname;
```

Which equals:

```
echo ${'number'};
```

But as kingkero pointed out: You probably want to do something like `${'number'.$index}` and that is easier solved with arrays.

Comment: Don't even need that. `echo $$varname;`.

Comment: Missing a $ before varname, but this worked, thanks!

Comment: Heh thanks Niet, didn't know that was possible :)